# How do stop web reports in GeneXus from throwing and error when compiling in a Windows UI

Tags: build, genexus

In GeneXus Evo 2 is there a way to tell the compiler when something is web and when it is windows? When GeneXus is set to a windows UI it tries to compile my web reports (which are not called by any windows program)? The web reports are throwing errors and will not let my application compile successfully.

Comment: Can you post the compilation error?
When you say "web reports", you mean a procedure with print blocks? 
Are the reports configured as main programs? In case they are, which generator is selected in the Generator property (under Main object properties)? Or else, what is your default generator?

Comment: Here's some the compilation errors:

Comment: apwpthrttprv.cs(213,41): error CS0103: The name 'remoteHandle' does not exist in the current context
apwpthrttprv.cs(213,55): error CS0103: The name 'jContext' does not exist in the current context
apwpthrttprv.cs(499,35): error CS0103: The name 'remoteHandle' does not exist in the current context
apwpthrttprv.cs(499,49): error CS0103: The name 'jContext' does not exist in the current context
apfpthaplg.cs(196,97): error CS0103: The name 'remoteHandle' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Yes, they are procedures with print blocks. Yes, they are configured as mains. the generator is the default, I tried changing to the web generation but it didn't do anything.

Comment: I tried just running the Win Main object only and it still tries to build the web reports.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to define a Web Main object and a Win Main object. Then if you build one of this main (instead of making a Build All), only their called objects will be considered for the generation and compilation process.

For more information about the build process, see http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/hwikibypageid?5692

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that in the reports that are causing you trouble, the only main objects that reach them (directly or indirectly) are main objects targeting the web generator. Main objects define the boundaries of the search for the generators applicable to any object, so if for instance your report is only reached by a main object that targets the web generator, and that main object is invoked from another object that targets the windows generator, then the windows object will fail to compile.

E.g. you may have a transaction T1 that is generated for both windows and web generators, and in the after trn event you are invoking a procedure P1 which is main and targets the web generator only. Then the windows source file generated for T1 will fail in compilation.

To work around this issue, you have to surround the invocation to P1 inside a [web] region.

```
[web] {
    P1.Call()
}
```

Comment: My web reports are only called by web panels. I checked the "References" on each web report.

Comment: Here's what I hope maybe a clue to what is going on. It is trying to compile a web report that has no references at all. I went and deleted the .cs file from the target directory for this report and it is now telling me the .cs file for this file is not found even though it is not called any place.

Comment: Is your default generator the windows generator, or the web generator? When genexus finds orphan objects not reachable by any main object, it specifies them with the default generator. Webpanels cannot be generated with the windows generator, so we ignore them, but any object referenced by an orphan webpanel that happens to be a valid windows object, will certainly be generated for that platform.